# Sr.No Not coming Properly in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, number-formatting, serial-number

**I want to show list of my product as below :**

```
Sr.No | Name | Type 
--------------------
1     |  aa  | 2
2     |  bb  | 2
3     |  cc  | 3
4     |  dd  | 2
5     |  cc  | 4
```

**But its coming as  below**

```
Sr.No | Name | Type 
--------------------
3     |  aa  | 2
5     |  bb  | 2
1     |  cc  | 3
4     |  dd  | 2
2     |  cc  | 4
```

**and when any new entry made then :
But its coming as  below**

```
Sr.No | Name | Type 
--------------------
4     |  aa  | 2
5     |  bb  | 2
2     |  cc  | 3
6     |  dd  | 2
3     |  cc  | 4 
1     |  ec  | 5     // this below are two new entry made 
7     |  fc  | 4
```

**above should be  as below :**

```
Sr.No | Name | Type 
--------------------
1     |  aa  | 2
2     |  bb  | 2
3     |  cc  | 3
4     |  dd  | 2
5     |  cc  | 4 
6     |  ec  | 5     // this below are two new entry made 
7     |  fc  | 4
```

Its not that i want order by name , i just want normal  Sr.No as per entry .. means if i add any entry first then  Sr.No  1 , 2 , 3 and so on..

But when i add any new entry then its Sr.No get changed but it should get last sr.no

**Below is what i have tried :**

```
SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, orn.name, orn.type ,  u.* 
FROM  ofr AS u 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN  or_name AS orn ON u.id=orn.id 
GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY rowNumber AND u.add_datetime DESC
```

please note (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber  is generating serial no and this value is pass below under $cols "Sr.No" .... Sr.No is column name and nothing else ... its value is coming by " rowNumber   "

**Listing is call in below way :**

```
$result =   get_details()

$cols = array( 
        _("Sr.No.")=>array('align'=>'center'),
        _("Name")=>array('align'=>'center'),
        _("Type")=>array('align'=>'center')
       );

$table =& new_db_pager('tablename', $result, $cols, 'ofr','id',10); 

$table->width = "95%";

display_db_pager($table);
```

**Database :**

```
id : bigint(20)     UNSIGNED    No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
```

**Note :** above format is from http://frontaccounting.com/
       demo link : http://demo.frontaccounting.eu/

Comment: try with - `ORDER BY rowNumber, u.add_datetime DESC`

Comment: hey that is also right .. but serial no not coming properly .. i means its not as per added date .. also when i add any new entry then sr.no get change .. but it should not happen ..as if i have add any new entry then sr.no allotted to new entry should be last sr.no +1   ... but it not working get changed

Comment: you can do it with php also.

Comment: i know count , count++  in while loop ... but here i am not using any while loop for listing its standard format of : http://demo.frontaccounting.eu/  which there are calling in array pagination ..and not getting how i can build the same in it

Comment: you are passing the data in `$result`, just generate it as needed.

Comment: yes i know under $cols = array (_("Sr.No.")=>array('align'=>'center','fun'=>'myownfunction')); they have this 'fun'  option to create own function for particular column .. hence function myownfunction($row) { //generate sr.no  } .. what i can do here ..can u guide me ??

Comment: hence by using $cols = array (_("Sr.No.")=>array('align'=>'center','fun'=>'myownfunction')); i can do function myownfunction($row) { //generate sr.no }  but not getting how i can generate sr.no here

Comment: any one here ? ... still waiting

Comment: any one here ? ..still waiting .. pls help me

Answer (score 0):

After reading the question a little more carefully, I'm deleting my old answer and writing a new one.

It seems like you're trying to automatically assign a serial number to each new entry in the table, and you want that number to be persistent.  There is a tool specifically for this kind of problem: the auto-incrementing integer.  You never have to set this field when inserting records -- the database will assign the next number automatically.

In your DDL you specify that you want a field that is an integer, auto-incrementing, and not null:

```
CREATE TABLE ofr (
    serial MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ... the rest of your fields ...
)
```

When you query the table you don't have to do any fancy row-counting.  Just select the serial field along with everything else you want.

People use this all the time for generating unique IDs within a table.  It is often used as a primary indexing key, too.  More information is available at the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Hey slashingweapon : thanks for reply .. but i have used auto increment  system ... please check my question last line " Database :
id : bigint(20)     UNSIGNED    No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT "  ... reason i am not using this is .. suppose i have 1,2,3,4,5 entry and i delete my 4 or 3 number entry then new entry will be 6 not 4 or 3 ..also again the ordering will be change ..if i delete my 4 or 3 entry and new entry gets same number then it will be confusing ..hope u get my point what i mean to tell.... thanks once again ..hoping for another solutions.

Comment: Hey after here and there i just check with simple query as :

 " SELECT (cnt := cnt + 1) AS rowNumber,  u.* 
FROM  ofr AS u , (SELECT cnt := 0) AS dummy  WHERE 1 
GROUP BY u.id ORDER BY u.id DESC   "   -- AND GUESS IT WORKING I AM GETTING PROPERLY SERIAL NO ... I THINK THERE IS ISSUE WITH JOIN QUERY ???

Comment: yes i got it because of LEFT JOIN " LEFT JOIN  or_name AS orn ON u.id=orn.id  "  //// BUT FOR DEMO I JUST CREATED ANOTHER TABLE AND REPALCE ABOVE LEFT JOIN WITH IT THEN ..IST WORKING FINE .. BUT WITH ABOVE LEFT JOIN ITS NOT WHY SOO ...LEFT JOIN or_name ... database "  id smallint(6)   No  None AUTO_INCREMENT "

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  It just doesn't make any sense to me.  I don't understand why you don't just use the ID you already have.  From everything you say, it should do exactly what you want.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: auto-increment dont form proper serial no .. ex : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...etc .. because if we delete some entry then that number will not be seen again.. ex: if i delete 10 id then my new entry will be 11 not 10 ..which is not as per serial no ordering ..anyway thanks for the support till now :)

Comment: Well, yeah.  Serial numbers are supposed to be unique.  They are used once, ever.  One piece of equipment, one serial number.  If the equipment is destroyed, you don't re-use the serial number.  If what you're trying to do is number things by the date they were entered, then maybe you should add a date field and set it to automatically set to `now()` when a new record is created.  Then order by date and count the rows like you're doing now.  Pretty screwy, though.  Not really a serial number.

Comment: HMM.. tried that too ..added date column .. i think something wrong with my join query ..as if i remove join query then above thing works well but as soon as i used JOIN query then my serial no is not coming proper

Comment: You should probably stop calling this a serial number.  If you can come up with a different name for it, based on what you're really trying to do, then a better solution may present itself.  I think your nomenclature is getting in the way of a proper analysis.